# Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS Server for our database. It is working fine but some time it shown an error:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'HOSTNAME'
```

And when i am hitting my page two-three time it will gone.

Anyone suggest me, what is the issue while we are using AWS RDS with EC2 instance.